# How to use multiple for each loops simultaneously?

Tags: excel, vba, foreach

Below code is used to run a macro that takes multiple variables and loops through the range to fill them into another sheet and then save as a pdf.
With 1 for each loop it works perfectly, but when I try to use 2; it will run through the first loop once and then loop through the second loop only.

Any ideas to fix this?

```
    Sub CommandButton2_Click()

For Each c In Sheets("Resultaten").Range("N2:N1000").Cells '//Variable 1 range
    If c = "" Then Exit For '//To end the loop when cells are empty
        Sheets("Invuldocument").Range("B5").Value = c.Value '//Variable 1 transfer
For Each w In Sheets("Resultaten").Range("W2:W1000").Cells '//Variable 2 range
    If w = "" Then Exit For '//To end the loop when cells are empty
        Sheets("Invuldocument").Range("J5").Value = w.Value '//Variable 2 transfer
Application.Wait Now + #12:00:01 AM# ' //timer if the pc cannot handle the speed

Dim FileName As String '//Code below is to save as PDF in every loop
Dim Path As String
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Path = "C:\Users\802435\Desktop\test12\"
FileName = "PRO-" & Range("B5").Value & "-" & Range("D41").Value & ".pdf"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Path & FileName, xlOpenXMLWorkbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Next '//Repeat for every Variable in the list until Exit For
Next '//No idea why i need this
End Sub
```

Comment: Your w loop writes to J5, but the filename use D41. Is that what you intend? Also, with two loops of almost 1000 rows each, you'll write almost 1 million files. That doesn't seem right.

Comment: Not an answer to your question - but a way to find errors: use correct indenting so that you see what code runs within which loop.

Comment: @Solver Max The loops write to different locations in the sheet, but the filename has to be fixed to D41, that is intended. The two loops i designed to 1000 as a possibility, usually they will only need to loop through a range of 20-50 values. The problem is that i want one loop to finish and then go to the next loop, return to the first loop when the second is finished.

Comment: I think you need to explain the intention of what are you trying to do with the 2 loops, is it to loop through row 2 - 1000 from `Resultaten` worksheet and paste its value into `Invuldocument` worksheet (column N to `B5` and column W to `J5` cell)? If you keep pasting into `B5` and `J5` cell then you are keeping only the last value, is that intended?

Comment: @RaymondWu The intention is that whenever i press the button: 
Resultaten worksheet N2 pastes the value to Invuldocument worksheet B5, then
Resultaten worksheet W2 pastes the value to Invuldocument worksheet J5, then it waits a second before saving the pdf and go to the next value in the loop.

So N2 to B5 & W2 to J5, pause, save as pdf, N3 to B5 & W3 to J5, pause, save as pdf..

Comment: @foxed In that case, i will provide answer for the loop issue, you have to fill in the gap yourselves (saving as PDF). I don't think you need to pause it so I will exclude it from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to loop through the row number then do a check if the value in both column N and W exist, if it does then it will copy the value to the 2 cells `Invuldocument` worksheet.

```
Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Const Path As String = "C:\Users\802435\Desktop\test12\" 'Assuming that the path don't change, you can declare it as a constant variable
    
    Dim resultWS As Worksheet
    Set resultWS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Resultaten")
    
    Dim invulWS As Worksheet
    Set invulWS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Invuldocument")
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To 1000
        If resultWS.Cells(i, "N").Value <> "" And resultWS.Cells(i, "W").Value <> "" Then
            invulWS.Cells(5, "B").Value = resultWS.Cells(i, "N").Value
            invulWS.Cells(5, "J").Value = resultWS.Cells(i, "W").Value
                        
            Dim FileName As String '//Code below is to save as PDF in every loop
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            FileName = "PRO-" & Range("B5").Value & "-" & Range("D41").Value & ".pdf"
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Path & FileName, xlOpenXMLWorkbook
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Note: I did not test if the code for "saving as PDF" works as it is out of this question's scope. You are definitely encouraged to fully qualify your range reference in the code that assign `FileName` as it is currently referring to `ActiveSheet` which might not be what you want.